# TimerTask pauses when screen gets locked

Tags: android, screen, timertask

In one of my Activities I have a **TimerTask** which works fine when the screen is not locked/off *but it seems to pause as soon as I lock the screen*. What do I need to do in order to run the **TimerTask** without being interrupted (regardless whether the screen is **on** or **off**

Thank you in advance!

```
class RunnerTask extends TimerTask 
{
        public void run() {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    if(intervalCounter_ < maxInterval_)
                    {
                        vibrator_.vibrate(vibrationPattern_, -1);
                        //System.out.println("Running...  -  " + new Date());
                        intervalCounter_++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vibrator_.vibrate(vibrationPattern_, -1);
                        //System.out.println("Timer ended...  -  " + new Date());
                        runningTimer_.cancel();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by executing my TimerTask inside an Android Service (in the Background). This made it possible to continue the TimerTask even after my screen was off.

Here is a good answer from a stackoverflow user which includes useful examples:
[Keep UI Thread running when screen is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005689/keep-ui-thread-running-when-screen-is-off)